# java overridden method not getting called

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying my hand at making a little mod for Minecraft.

This involves creating a custom WorldType.

So far my code looks like this:

```
@Mod(modid = HungryPillarsMod.MODID, version = HungryPillarsMod.VERSION)
public class HungryPillarsMod {

    public static final String MODID = "hungry-pillars";
    public static final String VERSION = "0.1";

    @EventHandler
    public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {
        WorldType HUNGRYPILLARS = new HungryPillarsWorld();
    }
}
```

and in HungryPillarWorld.class

```
public class HungryPillarsWorld extends WorldType {
    public HungryPillarsWorld(){
        super("HUNGRYPILLARS");
    }
    @Override
    public IChunkProvider getChunkGenerator(World world, String generatorOptions) {
        System.out.println("Custom getChunkGenerator is running.");
        return new HungryPillarsChunkProvider(world, world.getSeed(), world.getWorldInfo().isMapFeaturesEnabled());
    }
}
```

In HungryPillarsChunkProvider.class

```
public class HungryPillarsChunkProvider extends ChunkProviderGenerate {

    public World hungryWorldObj;
    public HungryPillarsChunkProvider(World world, long seed, boolean mapfeatures) {

        super(world,seed,mapfeatures);

        System.out.println("custom HungryPillarsChunkProvider is running and the super has been called.");
        this.hungryWorldObj = world;
        System.out.println(this.loadChunk(3,4));
    }
    @Override
    public Chunk loadChunk(int xPos, int yPos) {
        System.out.println("something from custom loadChunk");
        // my custom code would go here.
    }

}
```

No errors at compile or runtime, but my method `HungryPillarsChunkProvider.loadChunk` method is not getting called by the game. It still uses the original from `ChunkProviderGenerate`.
I can post the original Minecraft code here, but it is pretty large.

I have checked that it is not private or final.

I The method looks like this in `ChunkProviderGenerate`:

```
public Chunk loadChunk(int p_73158_1_, int p_73158_2_) {
    return this.provideChunk(p_73158_1_, p_73158_2_);
}
```

`ChunkProviderGenerate` implements the interface `IChunkProvider` if that makes any difference. I have tried making my own class do that as well, but it had no effect.

In the console I get this output:

```
[22:19:52] [Server thread/INFO] [STDOUT]: [com.impellar.hungrypillars.HungryPillarsWorld:getChunkGenerator:14]: Custom getChunkGenerator is running.
[22:19:52] [Server thread/INFO] [STDOUT]: [com.impellar.hungrypillars.HungryPillarsChunkProvider:<init>:19]: custom HungryPillarsChunkProvider is running and the super has been called.
```

But the last message ("something from custom loadChunk") is never shown and any other code I put in there never seems to run so what am I missing here?

Why will the game not use my new method when it gladly jumps through all my classes to get a worldtype?

Comment: Are you sure that `loadChunk()` is being called? If `loadChunk()` just calls `provideChunk()`, maybe `loadChunk()` isn't used any more.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I still have problems, but they have changed so my initial problem seems to be solved. If you could provide it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that `loadChunk()` isn't being called. If `loadChunk()` just calls `provideChunk()`, then loadChunk() may be a legacy function which isn't used any more.